# How can I get my Xpath query to loop its contents into new cells

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to get my Xpath query to output to new cell rows but I have not been successful.I am trying to get my output into colum A row by row instead of Row 1 Column A, B, C

My full code is at https://gist.github.com/3205801

Would it be best to use Axslx for this or is CSV the standard?

```
#Set encoding options to remove nasty Trademark symbols
  encoding_options = {
    :invalid           => :replace,  # Replace invalid byte sequences
    :undef             => :replace,  # Replace anything not defined in ASCII
    :replace           => '',        # Use a blank for those replacements
    :universal_newline => true       # Always break lines with \n
  }

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ie/en/ho/WF06b/321957-321957-3329742-89318-89318-5186820-5231694.html?dnr=1"))
#For each break create a ;
doc.css('br').each{ |br| br.replace ';' }

clues = Array.new
clues << 'Operating system'
clues << 'Processors'

CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  #1. Output the Clues header
  #2. Scrape the output/force encoding to remove special characters
    csv << clues
    csv << clues.map{|clue| doc.at("//td[text()='#{clue}']/following-sibling::td").text.strip.encode Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options}
  #end loop
end
```

Comment: I am trying to get my output into colum A row by row instead of Row 1 Column A, B, C

Comment: I have something for you but using the standard WIN32ole for the excel file not the CSV gem

Comment: Would like to do it in CSV or Axslx but the WIN32ole method sounds interesting.

Comment: Copy a summary of your code that demonstrates the problem into the question above. Don't link to it, because if the code changes or the link dies your question will be useless for anyone else searching for a solution to a similar question in the future.

Comment: Ok I have added a brief of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question but I think you want the data like this:

```
header1,value1
header2,value2
header3,value3
```

rather than:

```
header1,header2,header3
value1,value2,value3
```

If this is true you can do:

```
CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  clues.each do |one_clue|
    csv << one_clue
    xpath = "//td[text()='#{one_clue}']/following-sibling::td"
    csv << doc.at(xpath).text.strip.encode Encoding.find('ASCII'), encoding_options
  end
end
```